# Responsive case (relative/absolute units - element size)

Tags: css, responsive-design

```
<body>
   <div>
   </div>
</body>
```

```
div {
width:10vw;
height:10vh;
}
```

Is there any way to set this div that will be 10% of the full available window ? (When the window browser cover all the screen).
Last time I did it with script in JS but I believe nobody does this and only use css.

Instead I can use px but even with media queries I won't know how it will looks like in other screens.

Anoher option: Using max/min-height/width, but still I don't know what value I need to set from avoiding from the div shrinking  (every screen is different px) or just let the div shink to some point - but either at this way I don't know how it will look on other screens.

Thanks.

Comment: you are using VW and VH relative to 1% of the width of the viewport and relative to 1% of the height of the viewport so it will be adjustable according to the viewport why dont you try vmin or vmax

Comment: I don't understand your question, you are already using vh and vw units. You can use dev-tools of your browser to test different screen sizes. I don't understand what's wrong with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the `min-height` and `max-width`, you'll be able to control its size.

```css
div {
  max-width: 10vw;
  min-height: 10vh;
}
```

Empty `div` elements have a height of `0` by default so the `min-height` keeps it from shrinking to nothing.

`div` elements are also `display: block;` by default, which means the width is 100% of the containing element. Defining the `max-width` will restrict that dimension of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use max-height/min-height/width in percentages.

```
div {
width:10%;
max-height:10%;
min-height:10%;
position: fixed;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```